# Как узнать, какие есть свойства и методы у объекта

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

Для автоматизации своей работы я иногда прибегаю к макросам в Excel. Делаю их таким образом: сначала использую опцию "Запись макроса", а потом редактирую сам макрос.

Но сейчас столкнулась с тем, что то, что мне надо, невозможно смоделировать. Можно только отредактировать тот макрос, который имеется. Для этого надо в этом макросе изменить свойство или метод объекта. Но какие у этого объекта есть свойства или методы, я не знаю. Как это можно узнать? Мой объект:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP1/tabpACTG/ssubMAINAREA:SAPLSUID_MAINTENANCE:1106/cntlG_ROLES_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell")
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй `объект.GetType().GetProperties()` для свойств и `объект.GetType().GetMethods()` для метод.

Answer (score 1):

1. В редакторе *VBA* при записи кода подсказки появляются, когда после объекта ставится точка. Редактор предлагает варианты продолжения строки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. В редакторе *VBA* нажать *F2* (или пиктограмму с желтой раскрывающейся коробкой) - откроется окно *Object Browser* с информацией о классах, объектах и их свойствах
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]